# Receiving "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException" regardless of using Fluent or Explicit wait

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried using both Explicit and Fluent wait and could not make it work and still received NoSuchElementException. I want to mention that the element was found when using Thread.sleep and waits right after.

URL: https://vegas.netbet.com/help/
Hovering over "My Account" then clicking on FAQ > Then clicking on point 5, though I believe clicking on any of them will return NoSuchElementException.

This is the HTML

```
<a ng-click="helpService.toggleAnswer(qa.id)" role="button" class="dropdown_link" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <p class="title grTextRed">"Placeholder Text</p>
                    <div class="caret_holder">
                        <span class="icon grTextRed down fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span class="icon grTextRed up fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

Fluent Wait:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> fWait = new FluentWait<>(getWebDriver())
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); // org.openqa.selenium
```

Explicit Wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait) new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

So far I have tried most of of the things from ExpectedConditions.

Also, the waits do not seem to ignore the NoSuchElementException as it's still displayed

Comment: I have added the URL in the original post along with the steps I am following until the issue appears @AbiSaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
driver.get("https://vegas.netbet.com/help/my-account/faqs");
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(".//p[@class='title grTextRed']")));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        
// to scroll the page to view the specific question
int question_num_to_click = 5;
if (question_num_to_click != 1) {
    WebElement scroll_to_ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//p[@class='title grTextRed'])[" + (question_num_to_click - 1) + "]"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", scroll_to_ele);
}
Thread.sleep(1000);
        
// clicking on the specific question
WebElement question_to_click = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//p[@class='title grTextRed'])[" + question_num_to_click + "]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question_to_click);
```

Comment: I have used only the following piece code from your snippet along with the one that I already had in place and everything worked without any issues now.
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(".//p[@class='title grTextRed']")));`

Comment: Ok, good, no pblm.